# hibernate: how to map join table with extra column without JPA annotation

Tags: hibernate, list, hibernate-mapping

Assume I have the following classes:

```
class Student{
  String name;
  List<StudentClassMark> courseMarks;
}

class Class {
  String title;
}

class StudentClassMark {
   Student student;
   Class class;
   MarkType markType;   <-- notice this is the extra column that is causing problems
}

class MarkType {
    String description;
}
```

how do I map the list using a hibernate mapping file (so no JPA annotation)? Here is what i tried:

```
<class name="Student" table="PERSON">
    <property name="name" column="NAME"/>
    <bag name="courseMarks" inverse="false" cascade="all" table="STUDENT_CLASS_MARK">
        <key column="STUDENT" />
        <many-to-many>    <-- this is the section that I don't know how to do
            <column name="CLASS"/>
            <column name="MARK_TYPE"/>
        </many-to-many>
    </bag>
</class>
```

The examples I found are all using JPA notation which I can't use.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured it out. Here is the correct mapping (I hope it helps someone else):

```
<class name="Student" table="PERSON">
    <property name="name" column="NAME"/>
    <bag name="courseMarks" inverse="false" cascade="all" table="STUDENT_CLASS_MARK">
        <key column="STUDENT" />
         <composite-element class="StudentClassMark">
             <many-to-one name="class" column="CLASS" />
             <many-to-one name="markType" column="MARK_TYPE" />
         </composite-element>
    </bag>
</class>

<class name="StudentClassMark" table="StudentClassMark">
   <property name="description" column="DESCRIPTION"/>
</class>
```